# fetch data javascript and push to array Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, cordova

i've got a Tricky problem...for now i'm working offline but soon i will get data from a web service.
Now when i scroll down a javascript listener push other data on a global variable...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           alert("CARICAAAA!");
           //window.gvariabile è la variabile globale che prenderà i risultati
           //new data li prenderò dal web service
           var newdata=["cocco","pera","melone","anguria","cocco","pera","melone","anguria","cocco","pera","melone","anguria","cocco","pera","melone","anguria","cocco","pera","melone","anguria"];
           window.gvariabile.push(newdata);
           alert(gvariabile.length);
          for(var i=0;i<newdata.length;i++){
         div.setAttribute('id2', 'd'+count); 
           div.innerHTML="<img src='img/eng_ico.jpg' class='logo'> <h3>"+newdata[i]+" "+count+"</h3><p>Dettagli</p><hr class='hor'>";
           }
          // alert("fuffa2");
          //rimetti lo scroll ad inizio pagina
           window.scrollTo(0, 1); 
       }
    });
```

the problem is that each time i load new data the lenght of the global variable increment of 1...not 20...(Except the first time that load correctly other 20 data)

and this is where i set for the first time the global variable:

```
function onDeviceReady() {

        //qua all'avvio carichiamo i primi risultati
        var risultati =["cocco","pera","melone","anguria","cocco","pera","melone","anguria","cocco","pera","melone","anguria","cocco","pera","melone","anguria","cocco","pera","melone","anguria"];
        window.gvariabile =risultati;

         for(var i=0;i< risultati.length;i++){

         var div = document.getElementById('d'+i);

         div.setAttribute('id2', 'dd'+i); 
         div.innerHTML="<img src='img/eng_ico.jpg' class='logo'> <h3>"+risultati[i]+" "+i+"</h3><p>Dettagli</p><hr class='hor'>";
         div.addEventListener("click", redirect_click(i), false);


         }

      }
```

Comment: Can you share your code as it is without extracting parts of it? Is the first block supposed to be a function? Or is it in the global scope?

Comment: stack prevent from insert too much code without some text....if i paste all the code it will not like it...anyway the first is a function that listen the window scroll...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, try to use [concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) function and set result in your variable, eg:

```
    var newdata = ["cocco", "pera", "melone", "anguria", "cocco", "pera", "melone", "anguria", "cocco", "pera", "melone", "anguria", "cocco", "pera", "melone", "anguria", "cocco", "pera", "melone", "anguria"];
    window.gvariable = window.gvariable.concat(newdata);
    alert(window.gvariable.length);
```